# How to adapt c# to c++

Tags: c#, c++, email

I am trying to send an email using c++. And it seems very hard looking at the answers online(i.e get some software or library or ...).
However i was able to find this code

```
string from = "andras.nemes@company.com";
string to = "john.smith@company.com";
string subject = "This is the subject";
string plainTextBody = "This is a great message.";
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, plainTextBody);
string smtpServer = "mail.company.com";
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

Which library should i include?
Or how else can i send an email without downloading poco or curl?
By the way i am not interested in adding attachmentsor anything.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: C++ doesn't have a built-in classes for sending email. So if you don't want to use a third party library I invite you to read the SMTP specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use .NET libraries in C++ if you use C++/CLI
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx

The thing is that if you do this your program will be a mixed of managed and unmanaged code.

If you don't prefer this option you can write a console C# application which receives paramters from your C++ app and sends the email and returns a result (error/success code).

Also a quick google search brought this up as well.

https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/vc.aspx

Depending on the context of your application, the amount of money/time that you want to spend and the environment that it will run at, One of the above might be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks, i already have a VB program that sends email, i might look into using that somehow. I have however read that it might be possible to do it with outlook from command line.